# how to create several child subElements having the same name as parent Element

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to create a xml file as following, with several subElements having same name as Parent Element.

[image]

I wrote the code as following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
TEST2 = ET.Element("TEST2") 
GROUP=ET.SubElement(TEST2,'GROUP')
GROUP.set('id','1')
GROUP=ET.SubElement(GROUP,'GROUP')
GROUP.set('id','1_1')
GROUP=ET.SubElement(GROUP,'GROUP')
GROUP.set('id','1_2')
GROUP=ET.SubElement(GROUP,'GROUP')
GROUP.set('id','1_3')

GROUP=ET.SubElement(TEST2,'GROUP')
GROUP.set('id','2')
GROUP=ET.SubElement(GROUP,'GROUP')
GROUP.set('id','2_1')
GROUP=ET.SubElement(GROUP,'GROUP')
GROUP.set('id','2_2')
GROUP=ET.SubElement(GROUP,'GROUP')
GROUP.set('id','3_3')

tree = ET.ElementTree(TEST2)
tree.write("TEST2.xml")
```

The result xml is like this, which is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite your `GROUP` with any new `SubElement`.
Change to the following:

```
GROUP=ET.SubElement(TEST2,'GROUP')
GROUP.set('id','1')
sub_GROUP=ET.SubElement(GROUP,'GROUP')
sub_GROUP.set('id','1_1')
... an so on
```